# Explain why two right triangles, each with an acute angle of 17 degrees, must be similar.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Two right angles with an acute angle of 17 degrees must be similar because triangles that are similar share the same angles.Is this proper?

Comment: You have two angles: $17^\circ$ and $90^\circ$ (it's a right triangle), so you have the third angle: $73^\circ$ (since the angles sum to $180^\circ$). Now use [AAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_%28geometry%29#Angle-angle-angle).

Comment: Study the properties of "Similar Triangles" as in http://www.mathopenref.com/similartriangles.html for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that all pairs of similar triangles share the same angles; rather the essential fact is that all pairs of triangles that share the same angles are similar.

You say they are both **right** triangles.  That means they both have a $90^\circ$ angle.  They also both have a $17^\circ$ angle.

It follows that both triangles have a $73^\circ$ angle:
$$
180^\circ-90^\circ-17^\circ = 73^\circ.
$$
So they have three angles in common.